# Installing TensorFlow in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I am having trouble installing Tensorflow in Anaconda Spyder.
I used Anaconda Cmd Prompt to > conda create -n my-env -c conda-forge spyder-kernels tensorflow

And I am getting this error when trying to print what version of tensorflow I installed using the code>>>

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf._version_) 

error:

runfile('C:/Users/matth/Documents/Python_Code/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/matth/Documents/Python_Code')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\my-env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\matth\documents\python_code\untitled0.py:9
    print(tf._version_)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '_version_'
```

As I stated above, I tried this code:
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.*version*)

and I am expecting the code to print:
2.0.0

Comment: Can you try tf.__version__? also can you provide the version information for  conda-forge spyder-kernels

Comment: `tf._version_` That is not the correct name.  Why are you using the wrong name?  Did you copy that from some example?

Comment: I got tf._version_ from the O'REILLY AI and Machine learning for Coders textbook

Answer (score 0):

Search online how to print python package versions.

The version number is usually declared as a Double Leading and Trailing Underscore (`__<var>__`) to indicate pecial methods or variable defined by the Python language.

So in your case type:

```py
print(tf.__version__)
```

Comment: YES! The double leading and trailing underscore worked. Thank you for the clarification.